# python - how to draw rectangle on image correctly

Tags: python, opencv

I want to draw some rectangles on the bmp images. And I have try some method:

```
im = np.array(Image.open('lenna_256.bmp'), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(im,(491,267),(529,305),(0,255,0),3)
cv2.rectangle(im,(10,510),(375,875),(0,255,0),3)
plt.imshow(im)
```

but the result shows that:
[The rectangle I draw shows here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ITZh.png)

However, I want to draw the rectangles directly on the original image, instead of the greyscale one, how could I solve this?

Comment: Convert the image to RGB.

Comment: you mean bmp is not in rgb format?

Comment: No, I bet it is a palette grayscale image. That's why your library (which is?) chooses the nearest color for your red.